# Huawei App Gallery rejects my app with insufficient reason

Tags: mobile-application, huawei-mobile-services

I've uploaded an app to Huawei AG but rejected by a message like

> "Dear developer, the functions in your App are unavailable and we can
>   not edit content in it after we logged in successfully, please modify
>   it."

My app is already available on the Apple App Store and Google Play store and working properly so I don't think that it is unsuitable. I've check [Huawei's review guideline](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/devservice/doc/30202) but couldn't find any solution.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: What is the name of the app? Did you try to submit an issue trough Huawei contact form?

Answer (score 0):

Your app has been rejected, and the rejection reason is "Dear developer, the functions in your app are unavailable and we cannot edit content in it after we logged in successfully, please modify it." Check whether your app has the problem. You are advised to test the relevant functions.